# How to work around "type interface has no field or method" error?

Tags: struct, interface, go

I want to write an abstraction to the mgo API:

```
package manager

import "labix.org/v2/mgo"

type Manager struct {
    collection *mgo.Collection
}

func (m *Manager) Update(model interface{}) error {
    return m.collection.UpdateId(model.Id, model)
}
```

When compiling I get "model.Id undefined (interface{} has no field or method Id)" which itself is obvious.

Is this a totally wrong approach from my side or is there an easy workaround how to let the compiler "trust" that there will be an Id property on runtime on passed structs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could defined an interface which declares an Id function

```
type Ider interface {
    Id() interface{}
}
```

If your model is an Ider, then your function will work.

```
func (m *Manager) Update(model Ider) error {
```

Considering the [`mgo#Collection.UpdateId()` function](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.UpdateId) takes `interface{}`, it will accept an `Ider`.

Comment: I thought of this too but wouldn't I then overwrite the default "Id" field which stores the actual Id? I though interfaces only define methods?

Comment: @bodokaiser as long as your object has an Id() method which can then return the default Id field, it is fine.

Comment: Ah so if I have a private field "id" then I can implement a Method "Id" which returns this and this is automatically used by mgo. Thank you!